# Trying to understand recursions

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static int fun(int x) {
    if(x<1){
        return 1;
    } else {

        return x+fun(x-1)+fun(x-2);
    }
}
```

im having some problems trying to solve this recursion for a given number. For example `x` could be 3 or 4 or something, what would be the outcome.

Comment: What output you got when you run?

Comment: The homework tag has been phased out of SO.

Comment: Did you run this and get an output?

Comment: Just run the code and see what output you get.

Comment: Is your goal to get the result of any given number, or to figure out why you get some number?

Comment: well i get the answer but im trying to understand how i got that number

Comment: so basically how this code gets that output

Comment: `fun(3)` -> `3 + fun(2) + fun(1)` -> `3 + (2 + fun(1) + fun(0)) + 1` -> `3 + (2 + 1 + 1) + 1`. It's **that easy** to do it by hand.

Comment: @AwsomeMan, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion this would help you

Comment: for example if x = 3 , the output is 12. But how does that come to be

Comment: Pasting some code and asking what this code do is not very good way to learn.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: No offense intended, but since you got it wrong, perhaps it's not _quite_ that easy to do by hand.

Comment: @Lincoded Really? Why don't you point out the major difficulty I'm supposed to have encountered? The innate inability to distinguish `<` from `<=`?

Answer (score 1):

When you call the function for x = 3, you get recursive calls which look something like this:

fun(3) -> 3 + fun(2) + fun(1){1}
fun(2) -> 2 + fun(1){2} + fun(0){1}

fun(1){2} -> 1 + fun(0){2} + fun(-1)
fun(0){2} -> 1
fun(-1) -> 1

which rolls back up into
fun(1){2} -> 1 + 1 + 1 -> 3

so fun(2) -> 2 + 3 + fun(0){1}
fun(0){1} -> 1
therefore,
fun(2) ->  2 + 3 + 1 -> 6

Then fun(1){1} gets called, going through the same process as fun(1){1}.

This all rolls back up into fun(3) -> 3 + 6 + 3 -> 12

Answer (score 1):

Try this to help you understand:

```
//do first call with trace ""
public static int fun(int x, String trace) {
    System.out.println(trace + " ENTRY x=" + x);
    int ret;
    if(x<1){
        ret = 1;
    } else {   
        ret = x+fun(x-1, trace+'<')+fun(x-2, trace+'>');
    }
    System.out.println(trace + " RETURN " + ret);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=3
return 3+fun(2)+fun(1)         // so return 3+6+3
    fun(2) = 2+fun(1)+fun(0)   // so fun(2)=6
        fun(1) = 1+fun(0)+1
            fun(0) = 1
        fun(0) = 1

    fun(1) = 1+fun(0)+1        // so fun(1)=3
         fun(0) = 1

result return 12
```

Comment: where is the error in this ?